# Facebook requests

Tags: php, facebook

I have made a facebook apps and users can send request to other users with that funciton

function inviteFriends(messagex, fr) {

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', filters: ['app_non_users'], 
    message: messagex},requestCallback);
}
```

Then in requestCallback function I save the request in mysql.

```
function requestCallback(response) {
    $.post("ajx/ajx.php", { "type": "saveRequests", "requests": response }, function(data) 
    {

   },'json');
}
```

In old applications everything working, but if I make a new app it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Facebook apprequests](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7192269/problem-with-facebook-apprequests)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there is no other JS errors? You can look at the in Chrome console, for instance.

```
function inviteFriends(messagex, fr) {
    console.log('inviteFriends:', messagex, fr);
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', filters: ['app_non_users'], 
        message: messagex},requestCallback);
    }
}
function requestCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

console.log('calling inviteFriends');
inviteFriends('hey', something);
```

Comment: There is no error in javascript, because I use that code on more than 10 apps.

Comment: Right. Then do `console.log(response)` in `requestCallback` function and check the exact response.

Comment: then something certainly wrong with your code. see example in my post